# How to filter a data.table based on values of Column where Column name is stored in a variable

Tags: r, data.table

Let say I have a `data.table` as below -

```
DT = data.table('Col1' = c(NA, 100), 'Col2' = letters[1:2])
```

Now I want to filter this `DT` for which `Col1` is `NA`. However `Col1` is stored in a variable -

```
Col_Name = 'Col1'
DT[is.na(Col_Name)]
### Empty data.table (0 rows and 2 cols): Col1,Col2
```

Any idea why I am getting 0 row?

However if I do

```
DT[is.na(Col1)]
```

I am getting correct result.

What is the wrong with first approach?

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: `DT[is.na(get(Col_Name))]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in a typical example of standard evaluation problem. With `data.table` it's quite easy to handle variable names. In your case, `get` does perfectly the job

```r
DT[is.na(get(Col_Name))]
```

See [a blog post](https://linogaliana.netlify.app/post/datatable/datatable-nse/) I wrote on the subject of SE vs NSE in `data.table`